# CakePhp twitter bootstrap autocomplete input select with options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.0

I've setup a form in cakePhp, in which I have a list of Cities. Here is what cake had generated for this select field:

```
<div class="input select required" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-title="City Id"><select name="data[Contact][city_id]" placeholder="City Id" required="required" id="ContactCityId">
<option value="">Select City</option>
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
etc...
</select></div>
```

I'm using twitter bootstrap.
When I'm trying to type in the beginning of a city name, nothing happens, it will not type, nor scroll to the matched city.

Comment: Are you using Javascript somewhere ? First, the autocomplete input is not a select, but a text input. See this link, it may help you https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me

Comment: Im familiar with the typehead.js, I guess I'm looking for more basic behavior, for example in this link:http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: comment Continue... This site shows a basic behavior that turns into something else. Well, I'm looking for the basic. Hoping I might have missed an option in cake input function or something?